# Blacklists in Lists Python, while grabbing data from webpages

Tags: python, list, blacklist

Basically, I have created a very messy code to grab links from bing search queries.
The problem I am facing, is that I am receiving too many bing related links.

I have tried this current code to remove these, but I would much rather prefer a blacklist.

This is my code:

```
import re, urllib
class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.15) Gecko/20110303 Firefox/3.6.15'
myopener = MyOpener()
dork = raw_input("Dork:")
pagevar = ['1','11','23','34','45','46','47','58','69']
for page in pagevar:
    bingdork = "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + str(dork) + "&first=" + str(page)
    bingdork.replace(" ", "+")
    links = re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', myopener.open(bingdork).read(), re.I)
    toremove = []
    for i in links:
        if "bing.com" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "wlflag.ico" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/account/web?sh=" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/?FORM" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "javascript:void(0);" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "javascript:" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "go.microsoft.com/fwlink" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "g.msn.com" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "onlinehelp.microsoft.com" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "feedback.discoverbing.com" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/account/web?sh=" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/?scope=web" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/explore?q=" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "https://feedback.discoverbing.com" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/images/" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/videos/" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/maps/" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
        elif "/news/" in i:
            toremove.append(i)
            for i in toremove:
                links.remove(i)
                for i in links:
                    print i
```

Suppose I inputted:
Dork: cfm id

The results I would get would be:

http://pastebin.com/eGgUKYwV

Where as the results I would like would be:

http://pastebin.com/Xi28BzXs

I would like to remove stuff like:

```
/search?q=cfm+id&amp;lf=1&amp;qpvt=cfm+id
/account/web?sh=5&amp;ru=%2fsearch%3fq%3dcfm%2520id%26first%3d69&amp;qpvt=cfm+id
/search?q=cfm+id&amp;rf=1&amp;qpvt=cfm+id
/search?q=cfm+id&amp;first=69&amp;format=rss
/search?q=cfm+id&amp;first=69&amp;format=rss
/?FORM=Z9FD1
javascript:void(0);
/account/general?ru=http%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2fsearch%3fq%3dcfm+id%26first%3d69&amp;FORM=SEFD
/?scope=web&amp;FORM=HDRSC1
/images/search?q=cfm+id&amp;FORM=HDRSC2
/videos/search?q=cfm+id&amp;FORM=HDRSC3
```

Basically, I need a filter that allows me to grab only VALID links from bing, and removes all the crap from bings side.

Thanks so much,
BK
P.S Sorry if my explanation is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the html parsing route with css/xpath quering using beautifulsoup, lxml or html5lib (with lxml.etree prefered), pseudo code:

```
html = htmlparse.parse(open(url))
hrefs = []

for a in html.xpath('//a'):
    if a['href'].startswith('http://') or a['href'].startswith('https://'):
       hrefs.append(a['href'])
```

of course this is pseudo code, you should adapt whether you use [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [lxml](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) or [html5lib](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

If what you are looking is more like sanitizing/cleaning up the page html based on a whitelist you might enjoy the use of [CleanText](https://github.com/amirouche/Cleantext), this program can be further customized to filter attributes using a regex but this is left as exercise ;)